# How do I insert a custom field value into a Wordpress dynamic_sidebar

Tags: php, wordpress, sidebar, custom-fields

To show a sidebar in a Wordpress theme you do this:

```
<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar' ); ?>
```

But I am trying to insert a value from a custom field where the sidebar name is so I have this solution which does not work:

```
<?php $field = get_field_object('section_specific_sidebar'); ?>

<?php dynamic_sidebar( echo $field['value'] ); ?>
```

I've tried many things and have searched quite a bit but I'm not totally sure of the language I should be using to search. Could anyone show me what I'm missing? Adding the single quotes around the $value doesn't work either it seems.

Answer (score 0):

What is the value of `$value`?
Looking at the [ACF docs](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field_object/) you likely want to use `name` or `key` as the array key.

Comment: The value would be one of several options from a select menu such as: "realestate", "community", etc. If I put $value outside of <?php dynamic_sidebar( $value ); ?> it will show up, but not when it is in the parenthesis. I think I need the single quotes but they aren't working so there must be some formatting that is off.

Comment: I guess to clarify, I want to be able to populate what is in dynamic_sidebar() with the value from a custom field. Can't seem to figure out how to do it.

Comment: You don't need quotes around the variable no. dynamic_sidebar requires the index, name or ID as the parameter. I would check what $field is using a print_r and look at what you are passing to dynamic_sidebar as it likely it isn't what you think it is.

Comment: Unfortunately, my knowledge doesn't go deep enough to understand your instructions. Thanks for trying to help, I looked into everything you suggested but I'm on a crunch and I'm probably going to try a less elegant solution.

Comment: If you do a print_r($field); you should see the contents of the array. You are looking for the key with the value you want (eg realestate); That would be what you use to as the dynamic_sidebar value.

Comment: I'm trying really hard to understand what you are saying but I have no clue how to do a print_r($field), I know just enough about php to do very, very basic stuff. I'm just trying to figure out what goes here: <?php dynamic_sidebar( ??? ); ?> Or I could be trying to solve this in the wrong way altogether.

Comment: Okay, you should probably read up on how to use PHP to be honest, but... before you do dynamic_sidebar(), type in print_r($field); that will output the contents of the $field array. From there you will see the key=>value. Where the value is what you want. so look at the key and use that as what you pass to dynamic_sidebar. I would take a look at the PHP docs on what an array is https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php